# Color Scheme for code not working - Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublimetext2, color-scheme

Sometimes Sublime Text 2 will recognize my code with its color scheme and other times it won't. I do a lot of pasting code into the code editor and editing it, but I rarely write code in it, mostly editing my older code. Its really helpful having the color scheme!

Comment: This might be a bug in Sublime -- Did you try the sublime forum http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/

Comment: Why I asked it here is because there is rarely anybody on Sublime Forums.

Comment: Well, if someone who uses Sublime were to try to answer this question, information such as what language, and a code sample that sublime does not recognize correctly would be helpful. Perhaps you can edit your question and add this information?

Comment: @SethUrquhart every single topic on the first 3 pages of the [Technical Support](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewforum.php?f=3) forum has been active within the past week.

Comment: I am having trouble with sublime at work. At home I installed it and the text color for at least the Java part was incredible. Colored fonts for every type of word. Went to work and told my boss and he told me to download it and then came to look and nothing but white code on black. I think this has to do with the setting preference but how can I turn that on. Is it something that has to be done because at home it came on immediately.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are just opening new files and pasting text in, the default syntax is "Plain Text", thus no highlighting. You can set the syntax in the buffer by opening the command palette and searching for "Set Syntax: ". If that isn't what is happening, please try to give more information.

-skuroda

Answer (score 13):

You can also set the coding language by clicking the bottom right corner "Plain Text" to open a list of languages to choose from. Click the relevant language and the Sublime will do the coloring according to your selection.

Answer (score 1):

Go to a color page and copy just the < ? and php from the top. Go to the white text page and highlight/paste.

Comment: try to highlight the keywords and be clear with the format it will help to reach out your answer for others

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. i had a problem with Arduino color coding but now i solved that with the help of this trick. You can also set the coding language by clicking the bottom right corner "Plain Text" to open a list of languages to choose from. Click the relevant language and the Sublime will do the coloring according to your selection.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript Syntax was not working for me, so changed to Java. Color shading appeared.

Comment: This section belongs to any possible answer. for asking a question please use the comment section.